# Rails ActionController parameters Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

This is my create method in users_controller.rb

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end 

private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

end

And This is my Users_controllers_spec.rb file

```
 require 'rails_helper'

 RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do

  describe "Post /create" do
   let(:user){build(:user)}
   it "should create user" do
     expect(User).to receive(:new).with({name: 'Naik', password: 'secret', password_confirmation: 'secret'}).and_return(User)
    post :create,  user: {name: 'Naik', password: 'secret', password_confirmation: 'secret'}
    expect(flash[:success]).to eq("User was successfully created.")
    expect(response).to redirect_to(users_path)
   end
  end
end
```

And this is the error I am getting. Am I missing something? I am new to Rspec testing so any advice on how to solve it would be appreciated.

[image: Anyone has faced this error before ?]

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure but try this: `expect(User).to receive(:new).with({name: 'Naik', password: 'secret', password_confirmation: 'secret'}.with_indifferent_access)`

Comment: you should try  `params = ActionController::Parameters.new(
        {name: 'Naik', password: 'secret', password_confirmation: 'secret'})
      user_params = UsersController::UserParams.build(params)
      expect(user_params).to eq({name: 'Naik', password: 'secret', password_confirmation: 'secret'}.with_indifferent_access)`

Comment: I tried them didn`t worked.

Comment: Try saying `expect(User).to receive(:new).with({name: 'Naik', password: 'secret', password_confirmation: 'secret'}).and_return(user)` Some examples can be found here and this definetely used to be working https://github.com/learnable-content/RSpec-collection/blob/controller_testing/spec/controllers/albums_controller_spec.rb#L3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue only when using Rails 5. Here is how this can be fixed: [How to expect a Params hash in RSpec in Rails 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557529/how-to-expect-a-params-hash-in-rspec-in-rails-5/38558338)

Basically this should be:

```
expect(User).to receive(:new).with(ActionController::Parameters.new( name: 'Naik', password: 'secret',password_confirmation: 'secret').permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation)).and_return(user)
expect(user).to receive(:save).and_return(true) # stub the `save` method
post :create,  user: {name: 'Naik', password: 'secret', password_confirmation: 'secret'}
# ...and then your expectations
```

Comment: Note the `and_return(user)`, not `and_return(User)` - in the latter case you get not an instance of the class, but the class itself.

Comment: 1) UsersController Post /create should create user
     Failure/Error: let(:user){build(:user)}
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `build' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::PostCreate:0x007fb74b5dc820>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Seems like you have some problems with FactoryGirl and that's a totally different story. To find example configuration you may refer to https://github.com/learnable-content/RSpec-collection/blob/features/spec/support/factory_girl.rb

Answer (score 2):

You can do `to_h` on the `ActionController::Parameters`. Then all permitted parameters will be in that hash:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  name: 'Senjougahara Hitagi',
  oddity: 'Heavy stone crab'
})
params.to_h # => {}

safe_params = params.permit(:name)
safe_params.to_h # => { name: 'Senjougahara Hitagi' }
```

I'm no rspec pro but I think you can do:

```
expect(controller.params.to_h).to be({...})
```